# ELMAH SMTP

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, elmah

I am using ELMAH to email error messages. Is there an elegant solution to query a database for SMTP settings rather than use web.config? I would need it to be done before each error is thrown.

The solution/s suggested [here](http://groups.google.com/group/elmah/browse_thread/thread/f87154e82c9fa6a6) are a bit hacky for me.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your hacky method, the only other option that I can think of is to roll your own version of the binary, like SO does.  You can find the source here:

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/trunk/src/Elmah/